# Flag based logging to disable/enable Select SQL Query log in JPA

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, log4j

I am currently logging all types of SQL statements. I want to enable/disable logging of the select statement based on a flag.
Log4j2.yml file is -

```
Loggers:
    logger:
      - name: ApplicationLogger
        level: debug
        additivity: false
        AppenderRef:
          - ref: LogToConsole
          - ref: LogToRollingFile
      - name: org.hibernate.SQL
        level: debug
        additivity: false
        AppenderRef:
          - ref: LogToConsole
          - ref: LogToRollingFile
      - name: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder
        level: trace
        additivity: false
        AppenderRef:
          - ref: LogToConsole
          - ref: LogToRollingFile

    Root:
      level: info
      AppenderRef:
        - ref: LogToConsole
        - ref: LogToRollingFile
```

And I also want to turn off Trace/Warning Logs. How can I do that?

PS -  If any more information is required. Please comment.